# How to create multiple objects inside of for loop with different names?

Tags: c++, object

I have this code:

```
// Generate objects from type DepositoFresco or DepositoNormal

number_depositosf = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;

int j;
for (j = 0; j < number_depositosf; ++j) {

    type_deposito = 0;
    id_deposito = "df" + to_string(j);
    number_paletes = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;
    number_produtos = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;
    capacity = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;
    area = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;
    distance = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;

    list_depositos.push_back(new DepositoFresco(type_deposito, id_deposito, number_paletes, number_produtos, capacity, area, distance));
}
```

This code works but what i want is to create objects with different names (in concrete, with the name in "id_deposito" variable). I tryed to do something like:

```
number_depositosf = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;

int j;
for (j = 0; j < number_depositosf; ++j) {

    type_deposito = 0;
    id_deposito = "df" + to_string(j);
    number_paletes = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;
    number_produtos = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;
    capacity = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;
    area = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;
    distance = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;

    DepositoFresco id_deposito = new DepositoFresco(type_deposito, id_deposito, number_paletes, number_produtos, capacity, area, distance)
    list_depositos.push_back(id_deposito);
}
```

But it's not working. 
Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: what type is list_depositos? the most code you posted is unnecessary for what you asking.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do but a few problems: `DepositoFresco id_deposito = new DepositoFresco` you're assigning a pointer to a non-pointer variable. Also in the first snippet you `push_back()` a pointer, in the second you do it with a non-pointer.

Comment: I think you want an std::map<std::string, DepositoFresco*>. So you can do `list_depositos[id_deposito] = new DepositoFresco(...);`

Comment: list<Deposito*> list_depositos

Comment: Also, keep in mind you have a Deposito*. So if you retrieve that pointer value from the list, you will have access only to the Deposito variables, unless you cast it to DepositoFresco. But that can be unsafe if you cast the wrong things. So you need to know what you are casting at all times.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create or modify a variable name from a string in c++, but there are a few workarounds.
Probably the one that works better in this context is an **hashtable**. An hashtable is a data structure that creates an one way association between objects, so that if you have an object O1 you can easily retrieve another O2 that you saved earlier.
In this case, you want to use a string to access a DepositoFresco object.

Firstly you need to include:

```
#include <map>
```

then create your hashtable like so:

```
std::map<std::string, DepositoFresco*> list_depositos;
```

save to it an read like so:

```
list_depositos[id_deposito] = new DepositoFresco(...);
list_depositos[id_deposito]
```

Hope it helps! :D

Comment: I think doing #include <map> is what you will need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class Deposito
{
private:
    int type_deposito;
public:
    Deposito(int type_deposito):
        type_deposito(type_deposito)
    {}

    void testFunc()
    {
        std::cout << "You called a deposito testFunc with type: " << this->type_deposito << std::endl;
    }
};

class DepositoFresco : public Deposito
{
private:
    std::string id_deposito;
    int number_paletes;
    int number_produtos;
    int capacity;
    int area;
    int distance;

public:
    DepositoFresco(int type_deposito, std::string id_deposito, int number_paletes, int number_produtos, int capacity, int area, int distance):
        Deposito(type_deposito),
        id_deposito(id_deposito),
        number_paletes(number_paletes),
        number_produtos(number_produtos),
        capacity(capacity),
        area(area),
        distance(distance)
    {}

    void testFunc()
    {
        std::cout << "You called a depositoFresco testFunc with id: " << this->id_deposito << std::endl;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int valormaximo = 100;
    int valorminimo = 0;
    int number_depositosf = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;
    std::vector<Deposito*> list_depositos;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < number_depositosf; ++j) {

        int type_deposito = 0;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << j;
        std::string numStr(ss.str());
        std::string id_deposito = "df" + numStr;
        int number_paletes = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;
        int number_produtos = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;
        int capacity = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;
        int area = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;
        int distance = rand() % (valormaximo - valorminimo + 1) + valorminimo;

        DepositoFresco* deposito = new DepositoFresco(type_deposito, id_deposito, number_paletes, number_produtos, capacity, area, distance);
        list_depositos.push_back(deposito);
    }

    if(list_depositos.size() > 1)
    {
        //Retrieve and cast
        DepositoFresco* retrieved_depositofresco = static_cast<DepositoFresco*>(list_depositos[0]);
        retrieved_depositofresco->testFunc();//Calls DepositoFresco::testFunc();

        //Simple retrieve
        Deposito* retrieved_deposito = list_depositos[0];
        retrieved_deposito->testFunc(); //Calls Deposito::testFunc()
    }
}
```

This should compile and work. Note: I made Deposito and DepositoFresco classes that may be different from yours. I am making assumptions based on what I saw in your code. Modify it to your needs.

This will build a list (C++ vector) of Deposito*'s like you showed you wanted. Notice the little example I am giving you on retrieval. I had to static_cast in order to call the DepositoFresco functions. If you do not, you will only have access to the Deposito information.

Now if you want to access these quickly based on the deposito_id you will need a Hash structure, in which case you would use std::map. See SlySherZ for a map example. I wont bother including code for that.